# How to return a boolean from axios to disable a button in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I read almost every answered question in stack overflow to solve this, but still, I cannot resolve this.
I am trying to call a function to disable my button in vue and the function is returning a promise instead of a boolean. How can I get a boolean value here?

```
                        <v-btn
                        medium
                        color="white"
                        style="overflow: hidden"
                        @click="runValidationTaskNow(index)"
                        :loading="isRunTaskBtnDisabled(index)"
                        :disabled="isRunTaskBtnDisabled(index)"
                        >RUN NOW
```

......

In my methods, I call this function that I mentioned in disable and loading.

```
 async isRunTaskBtnDisabled(index) {
   const Status = await Util.checkFeatureEnabled("Validate "+this.validationTasks[index].productName);

  // Status.then(value => value);
   return Status;
```

and the checkFeatureEnabled is from another file that is given below

```
async checkFeatureEnabled(featureName){
const reqURL = process.env.VUE_APP_GUIDE_UTILITY_SERVICES_HOST + `/api/checkFeatureEnabled/` + featureName;
console.log("reqURL", reqURL);
return await Axios(reqURL, { method: "GET", withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("ui"+response.data);
    return response.data;
}).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Here the `response.data` is true or false; I am getting that correctly from my DB.

Comment: You shouldn't directly call the function from the template. It returns promise object and cannot return boolean.

Comment: @EstusFlask i need to disable the button based on that function call's result. so how will i get that value there?

Answer (score 1):

change this part

```
return await Axios(reqURL, { method: "GET", withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("ui"+response.data);
    return response.data;
}).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

to this:

```
try {
  const response = await Axios(reqURL, { method: 'GET', withCredentials: true })
  console.log('ui' + response.data)
  return response.data
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
  return something
}
```

Comment: You should explain what he is doing wrong: the `await` part makes the promise return, so `await somePromise().then()` doesnt make sense since you do not need the `then()`.

Comment: in isRunTaskBtnDisabled , stored the value to something . then return that 'something , that worked